# Wrong top statement declaration error when defining an implicit method

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, implicit-conversion

I have the simplest code

```
sealed trait WhereCondition
final case class StringWhereCondition(condition: String) extends WhereCondition

implicit def fromStrToWhereCondition (str: String): WhereCondition = StringWhereCondition(str)
```

implicit method line unfortunately gives error

```
Wrong top statement declaration
```

from IntelliJ and I cant get what's wrong with it?

Comment: Possibly you are defining a method outside object or class. If you wish to do that try using REPL (Scala Worksheet in IntelliJ), or wrap the method within object/class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`def` line can't be top-level (in Scala 2). Put it into some object for example.

Comment: I'm a beginner in scala, i read an advise to declare case classes outside of other classes and objects, but it would me more convinient to write implicits just under the case classes declaration...It is possible to organize code somehow to get it?

Comment: @DmitryReutov implicits (`def`, `val`, objects, classes) can't be top-level in Scala 2. In Scala 3 they can https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/dropped-features/package-objects.html Another advice can be not to use implicit conversions. Normally implicits are for different things in Scala (type classes, extension methods, capacities...) Normally you put implicit for type `A` to companion object of `A`, of type `A[B]` either to companion object of `A` or to companion object of `B`. Then you don't have to import implicits.

Comment: @DmitryReutov Try to put your implicit conversion (if you really need it) `String => WhereCondition` into companion object of `WhereCondition`. Then sometimes you won't have to import it: `val x: WhereCondition = "abc"`, but sometimes you'll have: `import WhereCondition._; "abc".some_method_from_WhereCondition`.

Comment: Nice, thanx for advise (i dont realy need it, i just do some project for educational purpose)